# Launch image fine on iPhone, cropped on iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, crop, launch

I have an iPhone app with a 320x480 Launch Image in the image well in the Target Summary screen in Xcode. When I launch the app on the iPhone - looks fine (sim + actual device). However, when I run it on my iPad (sim + actual device) in either standard size or 2x zoom, the Launch Image is cropped…i.e., the right 80 or so pixels of the image is off the screen.

The Device Type for the app is set to iPhone if that helps.

Any ideas on what's happening/how to resolve would be most appreciated.
Thanks
Tony.

Comment: No, I'm using 4.5 but confirmed the same issue happens in 4.3.2.